# TCP Socket buffer and Data Overflow

Tags: c#, sockets, buffer

My application is acting as client for a banks server, sending request and getting response from that server. After response processing is done in database which takes some time, so If sever send response in 0.5 second and db operation takes 1 sec after which only my application again try to receive data from server through begin receive then should data will be accumulated somewhere and if yes where it will be stored. Is there will be some limitation so that data will be overflowed and if it happen whether it will closed this socket. I am declaring my socket buffer size to 1024. If anyone also have some article which clear my doubts please share it.

Comment: I had tested and find that even application is slow its working but want to where this data is stored if my buffer size is only 1024

Comment: either enlarge the buffer-size or store it in your own buffer or even better try to find out why your update on the DB is taking such a long time

Comment: Issue if not of db that i am doing intentnally. Reason is only find to

Comment: Issue if not db but i only want to know, if sender speed is higher then receiver speed then who ensure that data didn't lost and where it stored for this amount of time till receiver read all this data

Comment: continue in my answer before this comment-thread gets to long (and maybe I can have some rep for my time ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you control what the server is sending to you? In most cases when the receiver operates on the received data, sending an application-level ACK upon finishing the work will allow the sender to know when to send the next request. This will ensure no data is lost (since TCP will make sure it does not get lost in the network).

If you can't change the way the server sends you data, you can consider running the receiver in a different thread, where it will save every incoming request to a cache (either only in RAM or to the HD). Then, a worker thread (or multiple threads) will read requests from that cache and do the work you need. This way you will have full control of the buffering of the data.

Comment: I am agree with you, but my only doubt is if i don't have any control on server and its sending speed is far greater then clients receiving speed(It may not happened but just I need clarification) so what will happen. Whether data will be overflowed in tcp and lost and if lost whether it will close socket or it will remain there till client read all data.

Comment: The OS socket layer has an internal buffer. Its size can be controlled by the `ReceiveBufferSize` property. If this buffer gets full, it will either overwrite older data or drop new data. If the socket is closed with data still in the buffer, you can still read the data (since a TCP socket close is only for sending).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will read the data in chunks yourself with the Socket - don't you? Than just don't read more than you can handle. The sender should do the same - if your input-buffer overflows the sender should wait before sending more. But maybe there will be an error in this case. If this is really a big issue just start by downloading the data into a file on your disk and process the data after you got all of it. I don't think your HDD will be slower than your network :)

Comment: I am agree with you, but my only doubt is if i don't have any control on server and its sending speed is far greater then clients receiving speed(It may not happened but just I need clarification) so what will happen. Whether data will be overflowed in tcp and lost and if lost whether it will close socket or it will remain there till client read all data.

Comment: this will depend on your client and on the server - if the server does not check/wait after sending packages the bits might be lost somewhere in *space* - but don't fear: if you save to HDD first then on your side won't be much of a problem - your speed will be enough and all the other nasty details are handled by the network-infrastructures ;)